# WebRTC server that streams audio

Tags: audio-streaming, webrtc

Is it possible to stream live audio from a server (not client  to client) using WebRTC?
I'm looking at the examples and tutorials but I haven't seen anything like that yet.

Comment: It is, but you're going to have to use some of the newer APIs for generating that audio data programmatically on the client end.  In other words, this is only going to work on Chrome, and maybe Firefox depending on how you implement.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the native API documentation at [webrtc.org/reference/native-apis](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/native-apis).

This provides a [sample C++ application](https://code.google.com/p/libjingle/source/browse/#svn/trunk/talk/examples/peerconnection/client).

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC was created to build peer to peer applications, and you are not forced to create only client-to-client connections. You can have a look at [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552333/is-it-possible-to-use-webrtc-to-streaming-video-from-server-to-client/17560186#17560186).

Although, if you want a real streaming server, WebRTC does not use the typical streaming protocols to allow you to broadcast a stream, and ignore the applications that are indeed "listening" for your data.