# Is it possible a webRTC client receives stream from a media server

Tags: webrtc, live-streaming

To my understanding, the webRTC is for video chat between browser client which support webRTC.

I wonder is it possible to stream data from a regular media server (live camera capture) to a webRTC client browser? What protocol or encoding should i cater for?

I am really new to this field, too many knowledge to pick up. Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use WebRTC to streaming video from Server to Client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552333/is-it-possible-to-use-webrtc-to-streaming-video-from-server-to-client)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to send streams from and to a mediaserver using WebRTC.
Examples are [Asterisk](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+WebRTC+Support) and [Lynckia's Licode project](http://lynckia.com/licode/).
There are other solutions aswell, it depends on what you are looking for specificly.

In your case with a webcam streaming to clients, perhaps one of these [Licode examples](http://chotis2.dit.upm.es/) might give you an idea of your implementation.