# Serverside WebRTC (streaming camera)

Tags: media, webrtc

**Use Case (stream UDP video)**

Stream server-side web-cam (robot) UDP video to a client browser. We would rather lose packets than have the webcam struggle to keep up over a TCP connection via wifi which constantly cuts out.

**Attempted solution**

Start a Xvfb FireFox browser on the server and have that stream the webcam media source. I don't like this solution as it's not flexible for non webcam video and difficult to configure.

I'm looking for something that can stream an arbitrary media source to a WebRTC connection (including the greets & hand shaking). I don't particularly care which language it is, if something already exists in `node.js`, `python`, `C`, `java` or `Scala` I'll use it. Otherwise I suppose I'll get to work on the problem (in that case any guidance would be appreciated)

Comment: [Janus-Gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) has all that you want...

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminTrent, looking into Janus and the new https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc

Comment: Wow! I did not even know EricssonResearch released their code. I am going to look into it as well!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use WebRTC to streaming video from Server to Client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552333/is-it-possible-to-use-webrtc-to-streaming-video-from-server-to-client)